# Rails: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to GET all Activities (belongs_to :student) related to a Student (has_many :activities) using this in my controller:

```
@activities = Activity.joins(:student).where(student: {student_id: @student.id})
```

However I'm getting this as an error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student.student_id: SELECT
>   "activities".* FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "students" ON
>   "students"."id" = "activities"."student_id" WHERE
>   "student"."student_id" = ?

Comment: The stacktrace is probably a good indicator here, are you sure you have the schema correct? And also, why the need to `join` here, why not just `Activity.where(student: @student)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't do this?:

```
@activities = @student.activities
```

Your `Student` class should look like this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :activities

end
```

If you want to be able to access the activities for a student directly from the `Activity` class I would suggest using a scope instead.  Something like this should work:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :for_student, ->(student)  { where(student_id: student) }

end
```

You can use the scope in a few different ways:

```
# pass in the student directly
@activities = Activity.for_student(@student) 

# pass in the student id
@activities = Activity.for_student(@student.id)

# pass in many students
@activities = Activity.for_student([@student1, @student2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the student prefix:

```
@activities = Activity.joins(:student).where(student: {id: @student.id})
```

It's saying that it can't find a column `student_id` on table `student`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@activities = Activity.where(student_id: @student.id)
```

or

```
 @activities = @student.activities
```